# How do I get the size of a <body> element once rendered in webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, webkit

An HTML page can have many different elements inside it which make up the content of the page.
I want to know the total size of all of the content of the page.
NOT the size of the WebView window, but of its rendered content.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use WebView's `computedStyleForElement:pseudoElement:` method against `body` to extract styles of it.

Comment: It must be `nil` for ordinary elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: Ok I tried it, but it also gives the size of the WebView window, no matter what HTML content is rendered.  
I guess that Webkit being a renderer as it is, it shouldn't be so complicated to get its rendered elements size.
It's a pitty it's so poorly documented.

Comment: There is still an option to pass something like `offsetHeight` on the page itself via JavaScript to Objective-C using `onload` event. But... yeah, it's really complicated and dirty way.

Comment: You mean `document.offsetHeight` ? doesn't work. And the offsetHeight of the <html> is, again, the client height.

Comment: I'm starting to think something like grabbing every child of <body> and move it inside a good old table which will resize to hold its content and hopefully give me the size of it.